# How to prevent a compiled batch file store source in tmp?

Tags: security, batch-file, compilation, temp, cracking

I need a batch file compiler that doesnt leave the source in %tmp%, so it cant be cracked that way. If there isnt a compiler that can do that, is there a way to prevent it? I have tried AbyssMedia QBFC, but it just makes the file hidden.

Comment: I think you can not prevent it !

Comment: This can't be done, and is one of many reasons that all bat-to-exe converters are garbage. If you absolutely insist on keeping your source code hidden, _DON'T USE A SCRIPTING LANGUAGE_.

Comment: You can create the file with attributes delete on close. This means it doesn't get written to the disk but lives in the file cache. Also no one else can open it. `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. This is the best you can get with batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [Hackoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080770/hackoo): This can't be done.

A batch file is a Windows command script. Like all scripts being just a text file, also batch files need an interpreter for execution which is the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` for all versions of Windows NT (NT4, 2K, XP, Vista, ...).

All *bat-to-exe* converters simply embed the batch file compressed or even uncompressed into an executable. The created executable extracts the batch file into directory for temporary files and execute it as process resulting in being interpreted with `cmd.exe`.

So what all those *bat-to-exe* tools do can be done for example also with *WinRAR* by creating a self-extracting RAR archive which on execution extracts the batch file (and other added files) automatically into temporary files directory and executes the batch file which as last line deletes itself.

In other words *bat-to-exe* tools are completely useless tools in my point of view. [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) is right: *bat-to-exe* converters are garbage.